# What is the maximum and minimum value that will validate for a HTML5 input type=number using android webkit?

Tags: android, html, validation, webkit, range

What is the maximum and minimum value that will validate for a HTML5 input type=number using android webkit ?

```
<input id="number" name="number" type="number" value="3.4028e+38" />


//does not validate
document.getElementById("number").value = Number.MAX_VALUE ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximum Value that will validate is

```
var max = 3.40282346638528878701170117011496e+28;
```

Minimum Value that will validate is

```
var min = -3.40282346638528878701170117011496e+28;
```

Even if your input attribute max is set to 1.79e+308 it will only be able to validate up to this max number. Anyone know why that is ?

Comment: [the largest single precision float is 3.4028234 × 10^38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)